# High-Performant setImmediate in Headless JSContexts

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, javascriptcore

I'm running application logic through JavaScript in an iOS app with the help of JavaScriptCore `JSContext`s. Recently, the need to use some kind of Promise library emerged and unfortunately, the WebKit-native Promise implementation doesn't work in headless `JSContext`s. However, all the Promise/A+ libraries require some mechanism to dispatch a callback to the message queue, and in browsers, the option with the best performance is `setImmediate` nowadays.

However, neither `setImmediate` nor any of the mechanisms which are typically used in browsers to polyfill it are available in a headless `JSContext` (like `postMessage` or `MessageChannel`).

For that reason, I inject the following implementations for `setTimeout` and `setImmediate`:

```
@implementation JSContext (TimingPolyfills)

- (void)injectTimerPolyfills {

    self[@"setTimeout"] = ^(JSValue *function, JSValue *timeout) {
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)([timeout toInt32] * NSEC_PER_MSEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [function callWithArguments:@[]];
        });
    };

    self[@"setImmediate"] = ^(JSValue *function) {
        [function callWithArguments:@[]];
    };

}

@end
```

This seems to work fine. However, the performance impact of dispatching to native and back to JS is huge. The following microbenchmark might not be super-meaningful, but it shows the costs of making a roundtrip to native:

```
// takes around 10.5s for 1.000.000 iterations
[context evaluateScript:@"setImmediate(function() {});"];
// takes around 6.5s for 1.000.000 iterations
[context evaluateScript:@"(function() {})();"];
```

So the big question is: Are there any options to get `setImmediate`-functionality in headless `JSContext`s which have a smaller footprint than dispatching to native and back to JS?